# SQL Server Index rebuilding vs reorganizing

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I am using Michelle Ulfords [script](http://sqlfool.com/2011/06/index-defrag-script-v4-1/) to maintain indexes. The script is great, but as far I can see will only reorganize (not rebuild) any index on a table that contains a LOB (text,ntext etc.)

Given that SQL server won't allow you to include LOB fields in an index, is it impossible (or not recommended) to rebuild indexes on tables that contain them? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server does allow indexes to contain LOBS. Otherwise it would be impossible to have a clustered index on a table with LOBS, which is clearly not the case. And is also possible to add LOBs to non-clustered indexes, as included columns.

As for your question: it is possible to rebuild indexes with LOBs but only as an offline operation.